# Verifying that all fields of a unit has been suitably filled in

Tags: c#, validation, null, cyclomatic-complexity

I have unit class which have some properties, and I have acceptancePolicy table which contain values. If values (from one row) are true method should return true. The method is below. How can I improve that code? What I should do with if statements?

```
public async Task<bool> IsReadyToComplete(Unit unit)
{
    var acceptancePolicy =  await GetAllAsync();
    foreach (var policy in acceptancePolicy)
    {
        var isReady = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitBusinessUnitId) && policy.unitBusinessUnitId != unit.BusinessUnitId)
        {
            isReady = false;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitCostCenterId) && policy.unitCostCenterId != unit.CostCenterId)
        {
            isReady = false;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitLocationId) && policy.unitLocationId != unit.LocationId)
        {
            isReady = false;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitCategoryMask) && !unit.unitCategory.unitCategoryId.Contains(policy.unitCategoryMask))
        {
            isReady = false;
        }

        if (policy.MaximalPrice > 0 && policy.MaximalPrice > unit.PriceTotal)
        {
            isReady = false;
        }

        if (policy.AcceptanceLevelRequiredId > unit.unitStatusHistory.unitStatusId)
        {
            isReady = false;
        }

        if (isReady)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to applay this:http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398607&seqNum=2

Comment: You can use `OR` with all condition for same value that is: `if((condition1) || (condition2)){statement}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if`
No purpose to setting it false more than once

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitBusinessUnitId) && policy.unitBusinessUnitId != unit.BusinessUnitId)
{
    isReady = false;
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitCostCenterId) && policy.unitCostCenterId != unit.CostCenterId)
{
    isReady = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts for what it's worth.  Hope you find them helpful.

```
public static bool IsReadyToComplete(Unit unit, AcceptancePolicy acceptancePolicy)
{
    // NOTE: try not to "go get" your own values.  have them passed in.  it will mnake unit
    //       testing much easier.   
    //var acceptancePolicy = await GetAllAsync();
    // NOTE: you can turn this into a linq statement, but i feel that's mostly a readability
    //       decision.
    foreach (var policy in acceptancePolicy)
    {
        // NOTE: it looks as though your original logic only needed one policy to be pass
        //       before exiting this loop.  maybe that's ok, i just thought i'd mention it.
        if (IsReadyToComplete(unit, policy))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// NOTE: break the method down to it's basic needs and pass in the policy
//       rather than going and getting it.  it's makes it significantly easier 
//       to unit test.
// NOTE: it also separates the meaning of the boolean result.  one method is true
//       if any policies pass.  the other method is true if a policy is passed.
//       so you don't have one bool var trying to accomodate both.
public static bool IsReadyToComplete(Unit unit, Policy policy)
{
    var isReady = true;

    // NOTE: in C# properties and values start with an upper case.  consistency is key.
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitBusinessUnitId) && policy.unitBusinessUnitId != unit.BusinessUnitId)
    {
        isReady = false;
    }
    // NOTE: else if will short cut your logic and make it run more efficiently
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitCostCenterId) && policy.unitCostCenterId != unit.CostCenterId)
    {
        isReady = false;
    }
    // NOTE: you could OR these all together.  i think that's a readability choice.  i don't think
    //       there are any significant benefits from doing that.
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitLocationId) && policy.unitLocationId != unit.LocationId)
    {
        isReady = false;
    }
    // NOTE: depending on the complexity or reusability of these, you could make a method for each if.
    //       otherwise, if this is the only place they are used, just leave them in here. it's not hard
    //       to understand or anything.
    // NOTE: the "law of demeter" would suggest that depending on properties more than one level deep
    //       can turn into quicksand if you are not careful.  that's a harder one to wrap you head around
    //       if you aren't used to thinking about it.  but fyi.
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(policy.unitCategoryMask) && !unit.unitCategory.unitCategoryId.Contains(policy.unitCategoryMask))
    {
        isReady = false;
    }
    else if (policy.MaximalPrice > 0 && policy.MaximalPrice > unit.PriceTotal)
    {
        isReady = false;
    }
    else if (policy.AcceptanceLevelRequiredId > unit.unitStatusHistory.unitStatusId)
    {
        isReady = false;
    }

    return isReady; 
}
```